# Constraint on ID column that allows 0 and Nulls?

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints, unique

I have an existing column that has employee ID's, however duplicates are being brought in and creating multiple records when ID's are present (ie. 302938492). Some of the ID's are NULLs and some are 0000000's which are allowed. I'd like to implement a constraint to forbid the duplicates happening without affecting the NULLs or the 0's. Is there any way to do this with a Unique index?

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UniqueExceptNulls
    ON employees (employee_id) WHERE employee_id>0 OR IS NOT NULL
```

OR would a check constraint work?

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueint_emplid
  CHECK (employee_id>0 OR IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This is possible. But my head hurts trying to think how.

Comment: You cannot do the task with an `INDEX` or `CONSTRAINT` or `CHECK`.  But you can do it with a `TRIGGER`.  (My head hurts, too.)

Comment: If I remove all of the NULLS and replace them with a default of 0's, could I implement a check constraint as above without the NULL check?